# SugarCRM unable to include hooks

Tags: php, hook, sugarcrm

I tried to create a logic hook for the Cases module in SugarCRM. I put my logic_hooks.php file into the custom/modules/Cases directory but it's never included.

I put some debug in the include/utils/LogicHook.php file and the problem is in the call_custom_logic function:

> ...
>
> // declare the hook array variable, it will be defined in the included file.
>
> $hook_array = null;
>
> if(!empty($module_dir)){
>
> // This will load an array of the hooks to process
>
> if(file_exists("custom/modules/$module_dir/logic_hooks.php")){
>
> ```
>  $GLOBALS['log']->debug('Including module specific hook file for '.$module_dir);
>
>  include("custom/modules/$module_dir/logic_hooks.php");
> ```
>
> ...

The empty folder test succeeds but the file_exists always returns false (and if I comment this line, the include function throws an error too).

I wonder how this could work as if I read good the file_exists function takes only absolute path but it seems to work for every other SugarCRM user so I guess I have a problem in my configuration somewhere.

Any help is apreciated cause I really don't know where is the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, file_exists() can take both absolute and relative path. Verify that you have the file named exactly `logic_hooks.php` and it is readable to the user that is running your webserver.

Comment: Yep it was a permission problem, tahnks!

Answer (score 0):

If your sugar is working, he sets path automaticly, that's why you can call files like that.

Anyway as above stated check if file is named good and permissions are right